# DropDownList holds one more value

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, properties, listitem

I have `dropdownlist` which has items that text and value property of the item are set to primary key. Yes, I show primary key with text property and querying with value property.

I want also to get selected item's other property such as name without querying `dataset` that binds to `dropdownlist` or querying database.

How can I do that?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="ItemID" Value="ItemID"></asp:ListItem> // I want get item's name
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DropDownList` Aspx Markup :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDropDown" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="ItemID" Value="ItemID" ThirdValue="ItemName" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Retrieve value like this :

```
ListItem item = ddlDropDown.Items.FindByValue("ItemID");
string value = item.Attributes["ThirdValue"];
```

Comment: How can I set ThirdValue in server - side programmaticaly?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get only one property such as name, you might want to do that

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="ItemID" Value="ItemName"></asp:ListItem> 
</asp:DropDownList>
```

You can query with **Text** property which is primary key ItemID and get **Value** property which is ItemName with

```
SelectedItem.Value
```

Comment: If I want to get more properties?